# Which way is better/proper to compare to objects?

Tags: c#, compare

I'm writing tests for testing REST services using specflow. The subject of the test is checking whether the list I get from the service contains the proper objects.

I have sample data in the background section which is put into the database at every run and it will be cleaned up after every run. The point is that I know the exact data in the database and the objects should be compared are DTO classes.

There is a point in my test where I have to compare both the result of request calling (deserialized JSON string to `List<DTOObject>`) the REST service url and the test data (populated `List<DTOObject>`). So, I have two `List<DTOObject>`. The question is that which way is better to compare them?

A, I write a generic comparator class (I don't want dependency between my test libraries and the application), and the steps are

- passing through a method name (e.g. partner name)
- get an item from either list and invoke the method to have concrete data to find the same object in the other object list
- having concrete data looping through the another set and call the given method on every object in the list and compare the result I got in the previous step
- if the desired class is found than compare them using the equals method

B,

- take an item from either list
- looping through the another list and compare every item to the item I got in the previous step using equals method

At the moment I have this two idea how to do it. I already read a few articles about comparing and I don't want to make it more complex than it is needed. I mean, implementing IComparable interface, overwriting GetHashCode method. On the other hand, I'm not sure it would be good if the DTO class implement an interface for testing sake.

Maybe I haven't read enough or I'm too close to the problem. What I would like to ask you is review my two possible approach - I'm definitely not sure they are correct - and if you know an article about this issue please share with me. I do not need existing solutions - using other's code brainlessly is not my way -, I need hints where to go.

Articles:

- [article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400028/comparing-two-instances-of-a-class)
- [article 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411232/comparing-two-objects)
- MSDN stuff

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparing the Objects themselves you should overwrite the `Equals()` method.
Overwrite `GetHashCode()` too if there is even the slightest chance that at some point of time your object might be used as a key in a Dictionary or something like that.

You can then use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual()` to check for the equality of the two lists.
Instead of implemeting `Equals` on the object  you could also create an `IEqualityComparer<DTOObject>` and pass it to the `SequenceEqual` call, but I think implementing `Equals` is the more versatile approach.

Comment: Thanks, for you help! My DTO objects are implementing the [IEquatable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and I overwrite the Equals method. So that, I'm able to compare the two list using [Enumerable.SequenceEqual()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx). I must say, it's perfect!